# How to store list of files in MYSQL database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to store List of files in a single column in MYSQL database, In my mysql I have following column
ATTACHMENT LONGBLOB

and in Mapping file I have, 
    @Lob
    @Column(name="ATTACHMENT")
    /*private List attachment;*/
    private List attachment;

But I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob, since I am using List.

Is there any way to store List of files(.jpg, .txt and .zip files) in single column? 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="file_details")
@NamedQuery(name="FileDetail.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM FileDetailc")
public class FileDetailimplements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="customGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(name="customGenerator", strategy="com.abc.generator.ContactIdentifierGenerator")
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="ATTACHMENT")
    /*private List<MultipartFile> attachment;*/
    private byte[] attachment;

    @Column(name="USER_EMAIL_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String userEmailId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_EMAIL_ID")
    private UserDetail userDetail;


//getters and setters
```

Comment: Why don't you store a single file as a BLOB per record, per column?

Comment: Do you mean the contents of the files? Or the metadata about the files: name, modification date, size, and so on?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen- User can upload any number of files, so if we cannot. store one file per column.                                                                          @ Basil Bourque-Contents of the file

Comment: Then store the files row-wise.  Something preventing you from doing that?

Comment: I also have other columns, based on user email ID, ATTACHMENT should be placed in DB

Answer (score 1):

You have to create another entity (you can call it attachment), this entity will have an attribute file and a One to Many relationship with the entity that actually carry the list of files.
Lets say your actual code is like this :

```
@Entity
public class User{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Lob @Column(name="ATTACHMENT") 
private List<File> attachments;

}
```

You have to modify you user entity to this :

```
@Entity
public class User{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="owner") 
private List<Attachment> attachments;

}
```

And create the Attachment entity like this :

```
     @Entity
     public class Attachment {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        @Lob @Column(name="ATTACHMENT")
        private File file;

        @ManyToOne 
        private User owner;

        }
```

Comment: Like this you will have files saved in a separate table in the DB, each file in a row (each row contains a file and a fk to reference the entity to wich the file belong).

Comment: I edited my answer before you post your code, I made an analogy with user having multi attachments

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried but files are not inserting into database.

Comment: Is there any exception ??

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt make sense. Why would you want to put all files in one column. Even if you merge all files in bytes and store it in a single column, It would be next to impossible to read them separately.

You can store files in a different table and store name of files separated by delimiter in a single column